# How to avoid "Please Verify you are a Human" with python webScraping?

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests, screen-scraping

I have been trying to get some information of a website with python. I have tried using requests and selenium to get the HTML code of the website but I always get this HTML. I guess the website realizes it is not an actual person doing the search and therefore denies access. Is there any way to solve this issue and get the HTML code of this website?

```
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Access to this page has been denied.</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            color: #000;
        }

        a {
            color: #c5c5c5;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .container {
            align-items: center;
            display: flex;
            flex: 1;
            justify-content: space-between;
            flex-direction: column;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .container > div {
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .container > div > div {
            display: flex;
            width: 80%;
        }

        .customer-logo-wrapper {
            padding-top: 2rem;
            flex-grow: 0;
            background-color: #fff;
            visibility: visible;
        }

        .customer-logo {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
        }

        .customer-logo > img {
            padding-bottom: 1rem;
            max-height: 50px;
            max-width: 100%;
        }

        .page-title-wrapper {
            flex-grow: 2;
        }

        .page-title {
            flex-direction: column-reverse;
        }

        .content-wrapper {
            flex-grow: 5;
        }

        .content {
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .page-footer-wrapper {
            align-items: center;
            flex-grow: 0.2;
            background-color: #000;
            color: #c5c5c5;
            font-size: 70%;
        }

        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <!-- Custom CSS -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://d33a4decm84gsn.cloudfront.net/static/partners/perimeterx/perimeterx.css">

<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/zItNOfzbrqVGbb4QFYpPpcrw/recaptcha__es.js"></script><script src="/Z5wgH7n9/captcha/captcha.js?a=c&amp;u=ad14b320-8116-11ea-9d99-a1ff7eeb44e0&amp;v=&amp;m=0"></script><script src="https://www.recaptcha.net/recaptcha/api.js?hl=es-ES"></script><script src="/Z5wgH7n9/init.js"></script><a tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" href="/colleges/yale-university/?_pxhc=1587174500133" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; font-size: 0px; line-height: 0;"></a></head>

<body>
<section class="container">
    <div class="customer-logo-wrapper">
        <div class="customer-logo">
            <img src="https://www.niche.com/about/wp-content/themes/niche-about/images/about-home/stacked-green.svg" alt="Logo">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page-title-wrapper">
        <div class="page-title">
            <h1>Please verify you are a human</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="content">

            <div id="px-captcha"><div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lcj-R8TAAAAABs3FrRPuQhLMbp5QrHsHufzLf7b" data-callback="handleCaptcha" data-theme="dark"><div style="width: 304px; height: 78px;"><div><iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&amp;k=6Lcj-R8TAAAAABs3FrRPuQhLMbp5QrHsHufzLf7b&amp;co=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cubmljaGUuY29tOjQ0Mw..&amp;hl=es&amp;v=zItNOfzbrqVGbb4QFYpPpcrw&amp;theme=dark&amp;size=normal&amp;cb=19z4nanjwlu" width="304" height="78" role="presentation" name="a-s7me84fdbal4" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox"></iframe></div><textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid rgb(193, 193, 193); margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none; display: none;"></textarea></div><iframe style="display: none;"></iframe></div></div>
            <p>
                Access to this page has been denied because we believe you are using automation tools to browse the
                website.
            </p>
            <p>
                This may happen as a result of the following:
            </p>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Javascript is disabled or blocked by an extension (ad blockers for example)
                </li>
                <li>
                    Your browser does not support cookies
                </li>
            </ul>
            <p>
                Please make sure that Javascript and cookies are enabled on your browser and that you are not blocking
                them from loading.
            </p>
            <p>
                Reference ID: #ad14b320-8116-11ea-9d99-a1ff7eeb44e0
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page-footer-wrapper">
        <div class="page-footer">
            <p>
                Powered by
                <a href="https://www.perimeterx.com/whywasiblocked">PerimeterX</a>
                , Inc.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- Px -->
<script>
    window._pxAppId = 'PXZ5wgH7n9';
    window._pxJsClientSrc = '/Z5wgH7n9/init.js';
    window._pxFirstPartyEnabled = true;
    window._pxVid = '';
    window._pxUuid = 'ad14b320-8116-11ea-9d99-a1ff7eeb44e0';
    window._pxHostUrl = '/Z5wgH7n9/xhr';
</script>
<script>
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = '/Z5wgH7n9/captcha/captcha.js?a=c&u=ad14b320-8116-11ea-9d99-a1ff7eeb44e0&v=&m=0';
    var p = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    p.insertBefore(s, null);
    if (true) {
        s.onerror = function () {
            s = document.createElement('script');
            var suffixIndex = '/Z5wgH7n9/captcha/captcha.js?a=c&u=ad14b320-8116-11ea-9d99-a1ff7eeb44e0&v=&m=0'.indexOf('captcha.js');
            var temperedBlockScript = '/Z5wgH7n9/captcha/captcha.js?a=c&u=ad14b320-8116-11ea-9d99-a1ff7eeb44e0&v=&m=0'.substring(suffixIndex);
            s.src = '//captcha.px-cdn.net/PXZ5wgH7n9/' + temperedBlockScript;
            p.parentNode.insertBefore(s, p);
        };
    }
</script>

<!-- Custom Script -->



</body></html>
```

Comment: Funnily this is a measure to prevent what you are actually doing.

Answer (score 3):

It's clear the website is able to recognize your bot. Since I am not aware of what website you are trying to scrape, I can't tell if this particular method will work.

Try changing the user agent. By default, the user agent of the `chromedriver` is different from the usual Chrome browser.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver

options = Options()
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver,chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: I tried with the solution you proposed but It didn't work. I am trying to do a scraper of the website "https://www.niche.com/colleges/search/all-colleges/". I am trying to make a program where I pass a list of college names and I get an excel sheet with some information of those colleges from Niche. But as you can see I am having trouble getting the HTML code to parse it because the website it is detecting me. I already tried with requests and selenium.

Comment: Do you see a reCAPTCHA?

Comment: @AdarshPunj I have the similar issue. yes I see the recpatcha.

Comment: Have you found any solution?